# KeyError: 'class_name' loading Keras json file

Tags: json, keras, resnet, imagenet

I have downloaded json and h5 files for pretrained resten50 on imagenet. But, loading the json file gives me keyerror.

My code:

```
json_file = open('models/resnet50/imagenet_class_index_new.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

I am receiving the following error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mycom/keras-flask-deploy-webapp/app.py", line 155, in <module>

    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

  File "/home/mycom/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 213, in model_from_json

    return layer_from_config(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/mycom/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py", line 27, in layer_from_config

    class_name = config['class_name']

KeyError: 'class_name'
```

What could the issue? I reverted back to  keras==1.2.2 but the issue persists.

Comment: Are you sure this is a keras json model file? From the filename it sounds like something else.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes. you are right. That was a wrong file. I downloaded the correct file as shown here https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/